# Derived table parsed in universe designer fails in Webi

Tags: oracle, business-objects

I've run into a problem I've never had before. I've built a derived table with 4 result objects that, according to Universe Designer, works correctly. The table and all 4 objects are successfully parsed, when I run the table via the *Table values* option it returns exactly what I expect, in full agreement with the data our frontend is reporting. So far so good.

The issue I'm having is in Webi. When I bring any object from that table into a new report and run it I get the following error:

```
A database error occured. The database error text is: ORA-00903: invalid table name. (WIS 10901)
```

How is this possible? How can an object that Universe Designer and, I assume, our Oracle database both say works fine and returns data, give me this error when I use that object in Webi? I've rebuilt the table, rechecked all the table names and shortened them just in case, there are no unusual alphanumeric characters in any table name, what else can I do? Here's the code that works in the universe and fails in WebI:

```
SELECT distinct 
to_number(p.ID) as person_id, 
e.ID as EPISODE_ID, 
et.DESCRIPTION as episode_type, 
nvl(rfa.date_answer,e.start_date) as LAST_REVIEW_IN_PERIOD 
FROM 
PEOPLE p 
INNER JOIN EPISODES ref_e on (p.id=ref_e.subject) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN REPORT_FORM_ANSWERS ref_rfa on (ref_e.ID = ref_rfa.episode_id and ref_rfa.section_item_tag_id ='0AA384CC-DDD8-A85F-6B68-060CCD878DE9') -- Date of referral - Response and Rehabilitiation referral 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EPISODE_OUTCOMES ref_eo on (ref_e.ID=ref_eo.EPISODE_ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EPISODES tri_e on (ref_eo.NEW_EPISODE_ID=tri_e.ID) 
INNER JOIN EPISODES e ON p.ID=e.SUBJECT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @DerivedTable("DT_CA_RRRT_SUEligible") on (e.ID="DT_CA_RRRT_SUEligible".EPISODE_ID) 
INNER JOIN EPISODE_TYPES et ON e.TYPE=et.TYPE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN report_form_answers rfa on e.id=rfa.episode_id and rfa.section_item_tag_id in ( 
'C8AEC1B5-6115-20CC-E160-EC9CB3854752', -- End Date - Response and Rehabilitiation Assessment 
'6DC97CE9-CA70-042A-3894-44CA551440DB' -- Assessment end date - RRRT Assessment of Care and Support Needs 
) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @DerivedTable("DT_PBLTElementsWithDates") on (p.id="DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".PERSON_ID and "DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".service_start<ref_rfa.date_answer and ("DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".service_end>=add_months(ref_rfa.date_answer,-12) or "DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".service_end IS NULL)) 
WHERE 
(et.DESCRIPTION in('Response and Rehabilitation Assessment')) 
and 
ref_e.id=dbo.f_workflow_first(e.ID,'RRRT Referrals') 
AND 
tri_e.TYPE='RRRTHOSTRI' 
and 
e.end_date IS NOT NULL 
and 
"DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".SERVICE_TYPE_ID IS NOT NULL 
and 
"DT_CA_RRRT_SUEligible".TEXT_ANSWER='Yes' 
and 
nvl(rfa.date_answer,e.start_date) <= @Prompt('Select reviews to','D',,mono,free)
```

I'm at a loss. What is going on, what am I missing?

Comment: Compare the SQL statement in Designer vs. the one generated in Webi, do you see any differences? What is the statement that is actually passed to Oracle (either trace your session or use something like [SQL Monitor](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/558) to see the SQL statement)?

Comment: Hi Kristof - unfortunately i cannot show the SQL generated in Webi as it comes up with the following error when i try - Web Intelligence cannot build the query or generate the report. (WIS 30351). When i put the code into SQL Developer i get syntax errors as the code uses Business Objects specific references to derived tables.

Comment: Then when are you getting the `ORA` error? If Webi is unable to generate the query, then something else is wrong. Try using the Query feature in IDT (Business Layer) to create the same query and see where you end up (see [this tutorial](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-22100) for more info).

Comment: Hi - I'm getting the ORA error in Webi when i attempt to run a query including the result objects from the derived table. I forgot to mention, currently we are on BOXI3.1 SP5 so i do not have access to the IDT, just universe designer. The derived table performs flawlessly in universe designer, producing exactly what i expect it to produce when run with the "view table" option. I have not had a single error in the universe designer related to this derived table.

Comment: If you're getting the `ORA` error, then that means that Webi is executing the query and Oracle returns an error that the query is invalid. Thus, you should be able to retrieve the query that is passed by Webi to Oracle by using the means I mentioned. That will allow you to compare the queries and check what's wrong.

Comment: Ok so a solution has been found and frankly it's as baffling as the original error. All i have done is move the following line of code: 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN @DerivedTable("DT_PBLTElementsWithDates") on (p.id="DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".PERSON_ID and "DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".service_start<ref_rfa.date_answer and ("DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".service_end>=add_months(ref_rfa.date_answer,-12) or "DT_PBLTElementsWithDates".service_end IS NULL)) 



I've moved that line up 4 lines in the where clause and that fixed it. Why is this a thing that can even happen?